# Simple String Reflection

Tags: code-golf, string

Let's start by defining a **reflection** of a character in a string:

> Given a string with distinct lowercase alphabetical letters with no spaces such
>   as `abcdefg`, define a reflection of a letter in the string `c` as
>   moving it (without changing the order of any other letter) to a new
>   place in the string such that the number of letters originally to the
>   right of it is now the number of letters to the left of it.

Thus, a reflection of the letter `c` in `abcdefg` would be `abdecfg`. *Explanation: there were 4 letters to the right of `c` and now, there are 4 letters to the left of `c`.*

Some more examples:

> Reflecting the character `e` in `myfriend` would form the string `myefrind`
>
> Reflecting the character `a` in `axyz` would form the string `xyza`.
>
> Reflecting the character `b` in `abc` would form the string `abc`.
>
> Reflecting the character `d` in `d` would form the string `d`.
>
> Reflecting the character `e` in `ef` would form the string `fe`.

For more information or to try out some test cases, [here](http://cpp.sh/7b7bx) is a (somewhat long) program I wrote in C++.

### The Challenge

Given a string with distinct lowercase letters, go through each character alphabetically and "reflect" it in the string.

*Clarifications: The letters in the string are from `a-z`, there are no spaces, the letters are unique, and the string is at least 1 letter long and at most 26 letters long.*

### Examples

> Input: `dcba`. Output: `dcba`.

*Reason: First, reflect the `a` as it is the character in the string that comes earliest in the alphabet. You will get `adcb`. Then, reflect the `b` as it comes next in the alphabet, to get `badc`. Then, reflect the `c` to get `cbad`, and then the `d` to get `dcba`.*

---

> Input: `myface`. Output: `fyecma`.

*Hint: Go through the letters in the order `a, c, e, f, m, y`.*

---

> Input: `a`. Output: `a`.

---

> Input: `acb`. Output: `bac`.

---

> Input: `cwmfjordbankglyphsvextquiz`. Output: `ieabhqzugdltkfnvpjxsormycw`.

### Scoring

- The input and output can be given by [any convenient method](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2447/42963).
- Either a full program or a function are acceptable. If a function, you can return the output rather than printing it.
- [Standard loopholes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1061/42963) are forbidden.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so all usual golfing rules apply, and the shortest code (in bytes) wins.
- Accepting ~100 hours after posting.

### Current Winner

```html
<style>body { text-align: left !important} #answer-list { padding: 10px; width: 290px; float: left; } #language-list { padding: 10px; width: 290px; float: left; } table thead { font-weight: bold; } table td { padding: 5px; }</style><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/codegolf/all.css?v=83c949450c8b"> <div id="language-list"> <h2>Shortest Solution by Language</h2> <table class="language-list"> <thead> <tr><td>Language</td><td>User</td><td>Score</td></tr> </thead> <tbody id="languages"> </tbody> </table> </div> <div id="answer-list"> <h2>Leaderboard</h2> <table class="answer-list"> <thead> <tr><td></td><td>Author</td><td>Language</td><td>Size</td></tr> </thead> <tbody id="answers"> </tbody> </table> </div> <table style="display: none"> <tbody id="answer-template"> <tr><td>{{PLACE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr> </tbody> </table> <table style="display: none"> <tbody id="language-template"> <tr><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr> </tbody> </table><script>var QUESTION_ID = 162891; var ANSWER_FILTER = "!t)IWYnsLAZle2tQ3KqrVveCRJfxcRLe"; var COMMENT_FILTER = "!)Q2B_A2kjfAiU78X(md6BoYk"; var OVERRIDE_USER = 12012; var answers = [], answers_hash, answer_ids, answer_page = 1, more_answers = true, comment_page; function answersUrl(index) { return "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/" + QUESTION_ID + "/answers?page=" + index + "&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter=" + ANSWER_FILTER; } function commentUrl(index, answers) { return "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/" + answers.join(';') + "/comments?page=" + index + "&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter=" + COMMENT_FILTER; } function getAnswers() { jQuery.ajax({ url: answersUrl(answer_page++), method: "get", dataType: "jsonp", crossDomain: true, success: function (data) { answers.push.apply(answers, data.items); answers_hash = []; answer_ids = []; data.items.forEach(function(a) { a.comments = []; var id = +a.share_link.match(/\d+/); answer_ids.push(id); answers_hash[id] = a; }); if (!data.has_more) more_answers = false; comment_page = 1; getComments(); } }); } function getComments() { jQuery.ajax({ url: commentUrl(comment_page++, answer_ids), method: "get", dataType: "jsonp", crossDomain: true, success: function (data) { data.items.forEach(function(c) { if (c.owner.user_id === OVERRIDE_USER) answers_hash[c.post_id].comments.push(c); }); if (data.has_more) getComments(); else if (more_answers) getAnswers(); else process(); } }); } getAnswers(); var SCORE_REG = /<h\d>\s*([^\n,<]*(?:<(?:[^\n>]*>[^\n<]*<\/[^\n>]*>)[^\n,<]*)*),.*?(\d+)(?=[^\n\d<>]*(?:<(?:s>[^\n<>]*<\/s>|[^\n<>]+>)[^\n\d<>]*)*<\/h\d>)/; var OVERRIDE_REG = /^Override\s*header:\s*/i; function getAuthorName(a) { return a.owner.display_name; } function process() { var valid = []; answers.forEach(function(a) { var body = a.body; a.comments.forEach(function(c) { if(OVERRIDE_REG.test(c.body)) body = '<h1>' + c.body.replace(OVERRIDE_REG, '') + '</h1>'; }); var match = body.match(SCORE_REG); if (match) valid.push({ user: getAuthorName(a), size: +match[2], language: match[1], link: a.share_link, }); else console.log(body); }); valid.sort(function (a, b) { var aB = a.size, bB = b.size; return aB - bB }); var languages = {}; var place = 1; var lastSize = null; var lastPlace = 1; valid.forEach(function (a) { if (a.size != lastSize) lastPlace = place; lastSize = a.size; ++place; var answer = jQuery("#answer-template").html(); answer = answer.replace("{{PLACE}}", lastPlace + ".") .replace("{{NAME}}", a.user) .replace("{{LANGUAGE}}", a.language) .replace("{{SIZE}}", a.size) .replace("{{LINK}}", a.link); answer = jQuery(answer); jQuery("#answers").append(answer); var lang = a.language; lang = jQuery('<a>'+lang+'</a>').text(); languages[lang] = languages[lang] || {lang: a.language, lang_raw: lang.toLowerCase(), user: a.user, size: a.size, link: a.link}; }); var langs = []; for (var lang in languages) if (languages.hasOwnProperty(lang)) langs.push(languages[lang]); langs.sort(function (a, b) { if (a.lang_raw > b.lang_raw) return 1; if (a.lang_raw < b.lang_raw) return -1; return 0; }); for (var i = 0; i < langs.length; ++i) { var language = jQuery("#language-template").html(); var lang = langs[i]; language = language.replace("{{LANGUAGE}}", lang.lang) .replace("{{NAME}}", lang.user) .replace("{{SIZE}}", lang.size) .replace("{{LINK}}", lang.link); language = jQuery(language); jQuery("#languages").append(language); } }</script>
```

Comment: Could anyone give me insight as to whether this puzzle is okay? It's my second one here (my first was closed as off-topic...whoops). I tried to make it really complete, but I'm not sure if I'm missing anything. I'd really like to improve and have fun on this SE! Thanks guys :D

Comment: This looks good. I might give a few longer examples (in particular, it might be good for the first examples section to present more than what are seemingly edge cases).

Comment: @EsolangingFruit Okay, thank you so much for your comment! I really appreciate it. Will do :D

Comment: Clarification request: "*the letters are unique*" means each letter occurs only once in input, is that correct?

Comment: Can we take the input and output in uppercase instead of lowercase?

Comment: @NL628 By the way, if you want to get insight on a challenge *before* posting it here, then post it in the [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2140/41024).

Comment: @GPS That is correct.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer Oh no! Was I supposed to post there instead? Aiyaa sorry about that...I'm really sorry :(

Comment: @KevinCruijssen I would prefer it to be in lowercase, but if you think of a really cool one, I'll edit the question to allow either ALL uppercase or ALL lowercase.

Comment: @NL628 No, nobody ever *has* to post it there, it's just a recommendation.

Comment: Okay @EriktheOutgolfer Thank you so much!

Answer (score 8):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 188 bytes

```
<>((((()()()){}){}()){}){(({}[()])<({}[(((((()()()()()){}){}){})()){}{}])<>{<>(({})<({}<>({}<>))((){[()](<{}>)}{}){{}(<({}<([]<<>{({}<>)<>}<>>){({}[()]<({}<>)<>>)}{}>)>)}{}>)<>}<>{}<>>)}<>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY1LCgNBCESvYy3mBuJFhll0hgyEfBbZBfHspjQdplvKQl7p5T1ur@V4jHummtRDfXiwZhfxWAUbtM1JnWRVew9i5rWLowrQlgAMea0R9TBEhXiiEVk3ZeoHqlENPq/qf9oZw2xNeZOUzOfnGPs1l/0L)

In addition to the reflections described in the challenge specification, this code also reverses the string exactly 26 times.  This has no effect on the final output.

```
# Push 26
<>((((()()()){}){}()){})

# Do 26 times:
{(({}[()])<

  # Subtract 122 from counter to get negative lowercase letter
  ({}[(((((()()()()()){}){}){})()){}{}])

  # For each character in string:
  <>{

    # Keep a copy of pivot letter on the third stack
    <>(({})<

    # Move next letter to other stack and compare to pivot
    ({}<>({}<>))

    # If letters are equal:
    ((){[()](<{}>)}{}){

      # Keep current letter separate from this transformation
      {}(<({}<

      # While keeping a copy of current stack height:
      ([]<

        # Move all letters to one stack
        <>{({}<>)<>}<>

      >)

      # Move a number of letters equal to old stack height back
      {({}[()]<({}<>)<>>)}{}

      >)>)

    }{}>)<>

  }

  # Destroy pivot letter
  <>{}<>

>)}

# Switch stack for output
<>
```

Comment: Wow that's pretty amazing. I can't even understand it :O +1

Answer (score 7):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>20</s> 17 bytes

```
{vð.øy¡€áÂ€gsJ£yý
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f@/uuzwBr3DOyoPLXzUtObwwsNNQCq92OvQ4srDe///Ty7PTcvKL0pJSszLTs@pLMgoLkutKCkszawCAA)

**Explanation**

With example for the first iteration of `myface`

```
{v                  # for each char y in sorted input
  ð.ø               # surround current string with spaces
                    # STACK: ' myface '
     y¡             # split at current letter
                    # STACK: [' myf', 'ce ']
       €á           # remove non-letters
                    # STACK: ['myf','ce']
         Â€g        # get the length of each string in the pair, reversed
                    # STACK: ['myf','ce'], [2,3]
            sJ      # join the pair back to a string
              £     # split into 2 pieces of the calculated sizes
                    # STACK: ['my','fce']
               yý   # join on the current char y
                    # STACK: 'myafce'
```

The string is surrounded with spaces each iteration as splitting on the first or last letter of the string would result in a length-1 list otherwise and the merge wouldn't include that letter.

Comment: 17 bytes?!??!! AMAZING..yet mnemonic is beating you by just one byte :P

Comment: Mmmm... Wow, only thing I could see is removing the surround with spaces. Seems odd we can't find another alternative to that.

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn: It's the shortest way I've found of handling a split of the first or last character. It does feel like a lot of bytes just for that though

Answer (score 5):

## Pyth, <s>18</s> <s>16</s> <s>19</s> 16 bytes

```
VSQ=QXx_QN-QNN)Q
```

[Try it here](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=VSQ%3DQXx_QN-QNN%29Q&input=%22ofxckieuqht%22&debug=0)

#### Explanation

```
VSQ=QXx_QN-QNN)Q
VSQ           )       For each character (N) in the sorted input (Q)...
          -QN         ... remove the character from Q...
      x_QN            ... get the reflected position...
     X       N        ... insert N...
   =Q                 ... and save the result into Q.
               Q      Output the final result.
```

Comment: Wow 16 bytes? I would upvote, but sadly I've reached my daily voting limit. Will do in 6 hours :P

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>80</s> 73 bytes

Thanks to Esolanging Fruit for reminding me that functions can return by modifying their argument.

```python
lambda x:[x.insert(len(x)+~x.index(i),x.remove(i)or i)for i in sorted(x)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYwxDoMwDEV3TpHNiUpZuiHRiwCDIY6aCpwqWFVYevU0UdXl@/np679OeQS@ZTdMecN9sahSP6bO80FR9Eask7l8qrCUtDdt6iLt4U2FQ1TeuJrKszpCFLKlPufqpLgREFoFuC717KfDlSrZdUGY@0a9omfR0hLbASa53icB0ygZNn8Ub/4NVxjZAnTP4Lk8Jv/Wvg)

Takes input as a list of characters.

Comment: Wow I wrote an answer in C++ and Python 3 also. My Python 3 answer was exactly twice as long as yours... +1

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 70 bytes

```python
def f(t):
 for c in sorted(t):i=t.index(c);l=len(t)+~i;t[l:l]=t.pop(i)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY7NEoIwDITvPEVuhVE5eITBF3E8QH8kWNpaooIHX72mekky@81mN2w0endMSWkDpqSqKcD4CBLQweIjaZVF7KhGp/Rayqq1ndWO1d0HWzrbxl6YBh9KrFL2UvaKXux5yCGveTO91PlScmAg5Gs2k49q6N3tarcwLk@90v2Bb8EFQkRHQAVQZ3Ehjip@3do/EHA48Q9RTx5zj/QF)

Modifies the input list

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript, <s>85</s> <s>80</s> 79 bytes

<sup>-6 bytes thanks to @DanielIndie</sup>

```
a=>[...a].sort().map(i=>a.splice(s=a.indexOf(i),1)&&a.splice(a.length-s,0,i))&&a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY9dboMwEISfyzF4iGzVsdoDmCv0AFGkLPYalvgv2CGQqmenULV9GumbGY1mgAmyHimVY4gGV6tWUM1JSglnmeNYGJceEiPVgMzJkUaWFUgKBucPy4iLd/76b4F0GLrSH7N4E8T54QBrwVwUo5AEzomr5rN60THk6FC62DHL9rXNPnM5RAqXi1J7sPqq9iar/WJBYy1qu6D2UPNfbnQLG/2RP6Yf3g5xNC2Ea@eW1OcJ53K703NLEkLb3573zrhytWFKw7w99It@1Hz9Bg)

Comment: this doesnt "compile" a is a string and you use splice

Comment: @DanielIndie Input should be passed as an array of characters, just like Jo King's Python solution.

Comment: [80 bytes](https://tio.run/##PY9bboMwEEW/yzL8EdmSM2oXYLbQBVSRMpgxmPgV7BBIlbUTqNp@jXTOvbqaASfMerSpHENsaTVqRVV/AQCeIMexcAEeE7eqRsjJWU08KwQbWpo/DbdCfojD4d8hOApd6Y9ZvksrdrUWykVxG5KkOQlVf1dvOoYcHYGLHTd8n9v0ScAQbTifldqD1bPam5z5xaAmJplZSHtk4pe3usGN/pw/pu/eDHFsGwyXzi2pzxPN5Xqzjy1pCZv@@rh1rSsXE6Y0zNuLftF3JtYX)

Comment: you dont return anything from that function, or print it

Comment: @DanielIndie Functions can return by modifying their arguments.

Comment: [79 bytes](https://tio.run/##PY9dboMwEISfyzF4iGzVsdoDmCv0AFGkLPYalvgv2CGQqmenULV9GumbGY1mgAmyHimVY4gGV6tWUM1JSglnmeNYGJceEiPVgMzJkUaWFUgKBucPy4iLd/76b4F0GLrSH7N4E8T54QBrwVwUo5AEzomr5rN60THk6FC62DHL9rXNPnM5RAqXi1J7sPqq9iar/WJBYy1qu6D2UPNfbnQLG/2RP6Yf3g5xNC2Ea@eW1OcJ53K703NLEkLb3573zrhytWFKw7w99It@1Hz9Bg)

Comment: You can save 4 bytes by changing `a.length-s` to `-s|1e9`.

Comment: @RickHitchcock Wait, how does that work?

Comment: If the first parameter to `splice` is a negative number, it's taken from the end.  So `a.length-s` is the same as `-s` *unless* `s` is zero.  In that case, we use `1e9`, which will be treated as the length of the array.

Comment: Any number between -1 and -512 bitwise or'd with 1e9 won't change.

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 51 bytes

```ruby
->s{s.sort.map{|c|s.insert~s.index(c),s.delete(c)}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PZBbbsMgEEX/vQo@ItFWLhuo6EaqqoJhiF9gh0di8ujWXQhJv@6co6sZaVyUadtpvr1/@otnfnaBGbFcrnD1rLceXfgtg8L1BV5bzxROGDDPt9umUBMXLentEkNL5hhyNqQy4TUZdML5bEdeeZYDQvjpVXY7/XWX3x9kqfU3Sgnnz11oVdOUE1SBFLR9ZFUmaQFYpE4I5qnvtX8AWVAKeAg4GT3MTklhx/2Uls4fcQ2H2J9Lr0chu8M57tUURm2Py7Dml5gEJ7r9AQ)

Takes an array of chars

Returns by modifying the input

Answer (score 3):

## Java 8, <s>140</s> <s>96</s> <s>92</s> <s>88</s> <s>87</s> 85 bytes

```java
s->{for(char c=9;++c>0;){int i=s.indexOf(c);if(i>=0)s.add(s.size()+~i,s.remove(i));}}
```

-44 bytes creating a port of [*@TFeld*'s Python 2 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/162907/52210).
-6 bytes thanks to *@OlivierGrégoire*.

Modifies the input List instead of creating a new one.

**Explanation:**

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##jZE9b4MwEIb3/gqLyRbBylpRkKqsbTKkW9XBHCYxAUx9hnwp/evUfERtqkqtBIOP13fPPeSiFUGe7jooBCJ5Fqo63xGiKitNJkCSZX8kpNUqJUBzF@eNVQV/NEYcnxTah8VWGAEuHxNkoUtf3OsetMIqIEtSkYh0GMTnTBsKLk0gug99H@J5yM5uFFERclWl8rDKKLBQZVTF0ZwhF2lKkaM6Scr8DzVDbmSpW0kVY@Hl0oXjqLpJCjdqmjiwlm4TurZGVZvXN8HGLaxES70UEuENpNdKeex3va39iAhIbguwL7NcmzQR1W5THOsttvJg3xt18iYLXw4GouHaSOREjUB/@OyvOHmV3P@WdGZ6m0gZL0X9oldJTiGIB8UMGAddFBLst5@G1khR8sX4QRvkVg@dGJt2qzjQfup0XB/RypLrxvLagdvi6pTn2vn1vNnAODUeQagMYul73v8A@j6uX08wabt0nw)

```java
s->{                     // Method with ArrayList<Character> parameter and no return-type
  for(char c=9;++c>0;){  //  Loop over all characters known
                         //  (except for the first 9 unprintables)
    int i=s.indexOf(c);  //   Index of the character, or -1 of it isn't present
    if(i>=0)             //   If the current character is present in the List
      s.add(s.size()+~i,s.remove(i));}}
                         //    Change the position of this character to index `l-i-1`,
                         //    (where `l` is the size of the input-List)
```

Comment: [`s->{for(char c=96;++c<123;){int i=s.indexOf(c);if(i>=0)s.add(s.size()+~i,s.remove(i));}}`](https://tio.run/##jZHLboMwEEX3/QqLla0Eqw@pUkWCVGXbJot0V3VhBpOYAE49hrxEf52aR9SmqtRKsPBwPXPmkIpK@Gm8aSATiORZqOJ0RYgqrDSJAEnm7ZGQSquYAE1dnJdWZfzRGHF4Umgns7UwAlw@JMgCl67d6x60wiogc1KQKWnQD0@JNhRcmsD04T4YjWByc3sXsJObRtQUuSpiuV8kFFigEqrC6TVDLuKYIkd1lJSNPtQYuZG5riRVjAV13QT9tG0ZZW7aMLTDzd0ydGmNKlavb4L1i1iJlnoxRMLrYM@V/NCue1n7EREQXRZglyepNnEkis0qO2zXWMm9fS/V0RtEfGnoiLprPZFz1QP9obS94vwVcvdb0plphSJlPBfbF72IUgp@2FlmwDjoLJNgv/03tEaKnM/6D9ogt7rrxNiwW8GBtlOH4/KAVuZcl5ZvHbjNzk55qp1fzxt3jEPjHoRKP5Qjz/sfQNvH9WsJBm118wk)

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Thanks. And 1 more looping over more than just the alphabet characters. :)

Comment: Well, if you go that road, `for(char c=9;++c>1;)` is better ;-)

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Ah of course, `char` also wraps around like `Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1 == Integer.MIN_VALUE`.. Smart!

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire `s` is an ArrayList, so `indexOf` will be of generic type `T` (which is `Character` for this input list).

Comment: Pffff... That's it: mixed the input type in my golfs... My bad. sorry. Deleting all my comments

Answer (score 3):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 61 bytes

```
$
a
{`(.)(.*)\1$
$2$.`$*_$1$1
+`(.)_(_*.)
$2$1
}T`_l`l!`.$
!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcxLCsIwEADQ/dyiMEISYSBewgu4FDKTNK3VtPbnp4pnj@36wRvj3HSSd@rIGUHgy4q0IqPPFgEPSIzGoUUL@02ccob0BhZ@J3aJU8GEUEDOZfAC7VJJiGskwUN4tdX1PpZeuludlv4yPeN7Hh7N5w8) Link includes test cases. Explanation:

```
$
a
```

Start the loop at `a`.

```
{`(.)(.*)\1$
$2$.`$*_$1$1
```

If the input contains the current letter, move it to the end, with a string of `_`s representing its original position.

```
+`(.)_(_*.)
$2$1
```

For each `_` move the letter back one character.

```
}T`_l`l!`.$
```

Increment the letter. After `z` change it to a `!` so it doesn't match anything and the loop ends.

```
!
```

Delete the `!`.

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>73</s> <s>72</s> 69 bytes

```r
function(s){for(x in sort(s))s=append(s[x!=s],x,match(x,rev(s))-1);s}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FY7BDsIgEETP@hW1l7IJHjybfol62G7BohSQpZVq/PZKL5OZybxk4qrbVU@OkvFOMHy1jyJXxlXsYyoFcIshKNcLvuRDyzeZ5YiJBpFlVPO2OJ7gzL91I3kjSdRYyxqpK9pTt4Vx0UiqGHqP@uFj36F73u0SBp5VTq/JfGqAar8jTCIgJyW0mJw1XE6kyMGaYmTTAIAkby0GVm2Jsrm6BtY/)

Inputs and outputs a vector of characters.

Comment: ew, using `c` as a variable name? that's awful, even for code golf!

Comment: Well, I can obviously change it, but I am really surprised to see that it could bother anybody here. I actually tend to give priority to preserving some sense in variable names (like `c` for `char`) rather than unused built-ins.

Comment: well, when looking for an improvement (which, I didn't) I found myself trying to use `c`, and it was awful when I couldn't figure out what was happening. I typically use `K` or `k` or even `C` just to avoid problems like that, but I totally get it. `append` is def the right tool for the job.

Comment: Oh, I see, sorry about that, will try to avoid setting such "traps" in future.

Answer (score 2):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), <strike>96</strike> 94 bytes

2 bytes saved thanks to Kevin Cruijssen

```
func[x][foreach c sort copy x[i:(length? x)+ 1 - index? find x c insert at replace x c""i c]x]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYuxEsIgEET7fMUNlY5jYZsm/2DLUJDjSNAEkJB48ecRGyfVztvdl8iUOxmpGtsWu3qUrKQNiTSOgLCElAFD3IGla08T@SGPHfD5Aje4gvOGuANbE7jenV@oCjpDojhppF8rhANUrEpMzmewIDT2ovmTwV4fcN5tFQ/FccT3bB8hmV775zDtcVw24vxa3UeULw)

More readable:

```
f: func[x][
    foreach c sort copy x[                  ; for each symbol in the sorted input
       i: (length? x) + 1 - index? find x c ; find its index and reflect it 
       insert at replace x c "" i c         ; remove it by replacing it with an empty char 
                                            ; and insert the symbol at its new index   
    ]
    x                                       ; return the transformed string
]
```

Comment: You can save 2 bytes by changing `find x c replace x c""insert at x i c` to `find x c insert at replace x c""i c` to get rid of an `x` and space.

Comment: @Kevin Cruijssen Thank you, Kevin, it's much better now!

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>23</s> 22 bytes

```js
¬n rÈ+S kY iYJ-XbY)x}U
¬n                     // Split the input into chars and sort it.
   r                }U // Then reduce the result with initial value of the input.
    È+S                // Append a space for replacing edge cases and
        kY             // remove the current char from the string.
           iY          // Insert it back
             J-XbY     // at the calculated index,
                  )x   // and remove the unnecessary space once we're done.
```

Saved one byte thanks to [Oliver](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/61613/oliver).
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn//9CaPIWiwx3awQrZkQqZkV66EUmRmhW1of//K@VWpiUmpyoBAA)

Comment: Nice one. You can replace `,É` with `J`

Comment: @Oliver Thanks a lot, I still forget to use the default variables every now and then, that's very handy.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>12</s>  11 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
W;ṢḟṁUṣ¥jʋ/
```

A monadic link accepting a list of characters and returning a list of characters.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATkAxv9qZWxsef//VzvhuaLhuJ/huYFV4bmjwqVqyosv////Y3dtZmpvcmRiYW5rZ2x5cGhzdmV4dHF1aXo)**

#### How?

```
W;ṢḟṁUṣ¥jʋ/ - Link: list of characters V  e.g. "myface"  ...i.e. ['m','y','f','a','c','e']
W           - wrap V in a list                 ["myface"]
  Ṣ         - sort V                           ['a','c','e','f','m','y']
 ;          - concatenate                      ["myface",'a','c','e','f','m','y']
          / - reduce with:
         ʋ  -   last four links as a dyad:
            -   (i.e. start with "myface" on the left and 'a' on the right 
            -         2nd iteration has that result on the left and 'c' on the right
            -         and so-forth)            e.g. left = myface, right = 'a'
   ḟ        -     filter out (right from left)      "myfce"
       ¥    -     last two links as a dyad:
     U      -       upend left                      "ecafym"
      ṣ     -       split at occurrences of right   ["ec","fym"]
    ṁ       -     mould (ḟ(x,y)) like (Uṣ¥(x,y))    ["my","fce"] 
         j  -   join with right                   "myafce"
```

Comment: Ok well this one pretty much wrecks everything else...

Comment: Well I think that's what Jelly is for - I half expect Dennis (Jelly's creator) to submit a shorter one!

Comment: Lol that's pretty amazing :P but I can't upvote b/c I used up my daily vote count..rip

Comment: ...I think there may be a way to save a byte by use of `ḟ`(filter out) but I have not managed it yet.

Comment: ...Beyond my comprehension :O

Comment: looks like, time-wise, it's O(n log n) in the length of the input since it first uses Python's `sorted` and then runs through n iterations of what appear to be less complex operations (flattening, splitting at found indices, joining, reversing). -- and Python's `sorted` is O(n log n).

Comment: Oh lol okay thanks! :D

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-p`, 37 bytes

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -p
for$a(a..z){s/$a//&&s/.{@{-}}$/$a$&/}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Dcg5EoQgEADAnHdQ1BrIRJvvVwYEj1VB8EKKrzvaYXsTxi@RdYHjB6W8qhyBI4AQEWT@5boU/gYXUIgarZBNyaI2DLVi@pjs4EKjcP63Y/Jd3M25Llt/sdv5tXdzpNo/)

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), <s>15</s> <s>12</s> 10 bytes

```
s(n/₌ṅtLnṀ
```

Thanks to @AndrovT and @TheThonnu!

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=1#WyJ+IiwiIiwicyhuL+KCjOG5hXRMbuG5gCIsIiIsIiFJbnB1dDogKFteXFwuXSspXFwuIE91dHB1dDogKFteXFwuXSspXFwuXG5JbnB1dDogbXlmYWNlLiBPdXRwdXQ6IGZ5ZWNtYS5cbklucHV0OiBhLiBPdXRwdXQ6IGEuXG5JbnB1dDogYWNiLiBPdXRwdXQ6IGJhYy5cbklucHV0OiBjd21mam9yZGJhbmtnbHlwaHN2ZXh0cXVpei4gT3V0cHV0OiBpZWFiaHF6dWdkbHRrZm52cGp4c29ybXljdy4iXQ==)

Comment: [I don't think the first `:` is needed, since inputs are reusable](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=1#WyIiLCIiLCJzKG7huobDtzpMJOKAn+G5gCRKIiwiIiwibXlmYWNlIl0=)

Comment: @TheThonnu Yes that works!

Comment: [It actually doesn't work on the rest of the test cases](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=1#WyJ+IiwiIiwicyhu4bqGw7c6TCTigJ/huYAkSiIsIiIsIiFJbnB1dDogKFteXFwuXSspXFwuIE91dHB1dDogKFteXFwuXSspXFwuXG5JbnB1dDogbXlmYWNlLiBPdXRwdXQ6IGZ5ZWNtYS5cbklucHV0OiBhLiBPdXRwdXQ6IGEuXG5JbnB1dDogYWNiLiBPdXRwdXQ6IGJhYy5cbklucHV0OiBjd21mam9yZGJhbmtnbHlwaHN2ZXh0cXVpei4gT3V0cHV0OiBpZWFiaHF6dWdkbHRrZm52cGp4c29ybXljdy4iXQ==) and it doesn't work if you add the `:` either :(

Comment: Yes needs correction!

Comment: Hope this works (o_o)

Comment: @AndrovT link is duplicated, don't see your answer!

Comment: oops, [10 this time for real](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=1#WyJ+IiwiIiwicyhuL+KCjOG5hXRMbuG5gCIsIiIsIiFJbnB1dDogKFteXFwuXSspXFwuIE91dHB1dDogKFteXFwuXSspXFwuXG5JbnB1dDogbXlmYWNlLiBPdXRwdXQ6IGZ5ZWNtYS5cbklucHV0OiBhLiBPdXRwdXQ6IGEuXG5JbnB1dDogYWNiLiBPdXRwdXQ6IGJhYy5cbklucHV0OiBjd21mam9yZGJhbmtnbHlwaHN2ZXh0cXVpei4gT3V0cHV0OiBpZWFiaHF6dWdkbHRrZm52cGp4c29ybXljdy4iXQ==)

Comment: Aha, thanks! I I thought of `₌`  but put it in wrong place (

Comment: @lesobrod yep, well done!

Answer (score 1):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), <s>164</s> 162 bytes

```c
y,n,a,b,c,p,i;f(char*s,l){for(i=0;p=0,++i<123;p<l&&(y=s[p],n=l+~p,a=p+1,b=p,n<p&&(a=n,b=n+1),c=l+~(2*(n<p?n:p)),memmove(s+b,s+a,c),s[n]=y))while(s[p]^i&&p<l)p++;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZBNktsgEIX3OgXlVFxCIjP2ZDeyknVWOYDjVAECCRsQBiRZnppc3UHWj2czu9ffe003Tb9RiXV5@yI0lU3BwM75QtRP1Y/oI7JCl4HdeqQRRgRRZJDIeEwrbBOHJHzjtY1FvslMvkFpKnbbl@@Z2cn1Ou5ztzcHpHOZ/jMI5ybdIpIbpHcmuDjXodLpFiI6JOKXJA7OT/1qIESKKVW3LHYpQS7FiELk9vqQ9xB2lZDBCE//Fet1GAVNmmbvN4qlHBcDiYPgLQImbO95vPqlTeNfwf6rO4Dfjb8XKwQczCLAYxeUt5Lp2MGBzF1D/I@ecu9RFChQWOh4ePs@Bu8PIAerghK8ykZERqR6jimbIR3hEiqmmpKZsJHQTvFjbQuC9amUvalcyy7@3IjrHORTK6EF42UljiepdG3O1vmm7S79EizH4LW/dG3jnT2bWit5Ooqq5GzaOBpPhsP/RkUWRRdVLIotii@qDCqyzDdWg81wpuckms49DHla7n2vZms8z8PkPaMKz@6Hrgej5EEJpjP//GKPuGCYVOdrUxbSn7huzfHiaqt62kXJ8@0/)

`f()` takes char-array containing input string and length of this array as parameters and performs required reflections in place.

`callf()` does pretty-printing.

## Credits

-2 bytes. @Kevin. Thanks

Comment: You can remove the space at `char *s` and change `i=96` to `i=9` to save 2 bytes.

Comment: Good catch.. we needn't start from `a`. Thanks

Comment: [144 bytes](https://tio.run/##dZDBcpswEIbvPAXjTDNg5CRObsY05576AJTOSEIC2UKskbAtZ9JXdyUI0EsvzL/f/rusfrqhEqvq/iAaaDuz16YU7VP9PVhAJ1TlyN0ihTAiCJBIeURr3K01kvEHb7tIZC9pkoj99vUthb18t5nOSQYFUplM/gDCmdrDO8lUskVqB@5LaAs20glGOiFIbrab13XkTa4dx0jnqsjs7iX228Ft1zkUv8Xjo9uexpAk6eedYimnQ@KPIAR3qeHR6oeC3uzC/Jsuwp@9GYoV0nEahDzSyL1IMhXp2INpxpt/qdH1GQQOhg0WKnJ7/Q9CnBfZqqQEr9IREA8ayzFlE6IezYZyqCiZauZremn4oe1KgtWxkhZqfWZXc@rFbbLxYYzQkvGqFoejbFQLp06b/ny52tlWedvNXi/n3ujuBK1q5PEg6oqzryuDMR7sHjQqMis6q3JWbFZ8VtUQxvM6@ErUb36aIx2qqTUmsTS5ZbTBU/efqYVRslCC6cT/H9FiFwyT@nTrq1KaI1dnOFx12zWWXoL18/0v "C (clang) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl](https://www.perl.org/), <s>74</s> 70 bytes

<s>84</s> 80 bytes including invocation as unix filter

```
for$c(a..z){if($p=1+index$_,$c){substr$_,$p-1,1,"";substr$_,-$p,0,$c}}
```

```
$ echo -e 'dcba\nmyface\na\nacb\ncwmfjordbankglyphsvextquiz' |
> perl -pE'for$c(a..z){if($p=1+index$_,$c){substr$_,$p-1,1,"";substr$_,-$p,0,$c}}'
dcba
fyecma
a
bac
ieabhqzugdltkfnvpjxsormycw
```

Answer (score 1):

### Haskell, 87 bytes

```
s#c|(h,_:t)<-span(/=c)s,(v,w)<-splitAt(length t)$h++t=v++c:w|1<2=s
f s=foldl(#)s['a'..]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Hci7DoIwGEDh3adoigltQIyOhA7uOjkSQkqhFCkF6Q@I4d3rZTjfcBS3baW1c9YTG1FhHgNNDnbghhyZoDYkc7j8j27gAkRXpgaFgO5VEACbg0DEy3ZKzszuJLJM9rrUxKM29bkfRZnreGMQQx0fbjkiwwR3GK8GRZKiFHer5KLCIea/RPFVLJ189GNZcNPWeh2UnasXPKfmjTP3AQ)

```
f s=foldl(#)s['a'..]         -- fold the function '#' into all characters from 'a'
                              -- with the starting value of the input string s
s#c=                          -- in each step (s: result so far, c: next char)
   (h,_:t)<-span(/=c)s        -- let 'h' be the substring before 'c' and
                              -- 't' the substring after 'c'. the pattern match
                              -- fails if there's no 'c' in 's'
   (v,w)<-splitAt(length t)$h++t
                              -- split the string 'h++t' at index length of t
   =v++c:w                    -- return 'v' followed by 'c' followed by 'w'
   |1<2=s                     -- if there's no 'c' in 's', return 's' unchanged
```

Comment: Why does this halt? Shouldn't folding over an infinite list cause an infinite loop? Shouldn't it be `f s=foldl(#)s['a'..'z']`?

Comment: @user1472751: `['a'..]` is not infinite, because `Char` belongs to class `Bounded`. A list with `..]` of `Bounded` values stops at `maxBound`.  Try: `print  [False ..]`.

Answer (score 1):

## [SNOBOL4 (CSNOBOL4)](http://www.snobol4.org/csnobol4/), <s>132</s> 128 bytes

```
	DEFINE('I(I)')
I	U =&LCASE
N	U LEN(1) . K REM . U	:F(RETURN)
	I ARB @S K	:F(N)
	I K =
	I ARB . L RPOS(S) REM . R
	I =L K R	:(N)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XU7JCsIwFDynX/FONrkUBE@FgNWkEBrTkjQf4L7VVq37z8cU9eJphtmYtm5mTTVwKMaMOMR4KhTHocCChCQQyALtyXFieKA8l1zhPoEIMtB84tGiOMWal1YrEiABiR7B0EDWyR8lA/ozIpCgi9xgQ7513VlUdnP@gCKO/T9AuS0LWwIVOJzfD6tdc17MpvV@XT2Pm/a2fFxO1@3LB7li7g0)

Straightforward implementation of the required algorithm. Saved a few bytes by switching to a function rather than a full program; the explanation remains the same, more or less.

```
	I =INPUT			;* read input
	U =&LCASE			;* alias for lowercase letters (it started out as uppercase)
N	U LEN(1) . K REM . U	:F(O)	;* set K to the next lowercase letter, and when empty, goto O
	I ARB @S K	:F(N)		;* set S to the number of letters before K, or goto N
	I K =				;* remove K
	I ARB . L RPOS(S) REM . R	;* set R to the last S characters of I and L to the others
	I =L K R	:(N)		;* recombine the string and goto N
O	OUTPUT =I			;* print new string
END
```

Answer (score 1):

## APL+WIN, 63 bytes

Prompts for input string

```
l←s[⍋⎕av⍳s←,⎕]⋄⍎∊(⍴s)⍴⊂'s←(n←⌽~s=↑l)\s~↑l⋄((~n)/s)←↑l⋄l←1↓l⋄'⋄s
```

Explanation:

```
l←s[⍋⎕av⍳s←,⎕] sort characters into alphabetical order

⍎∊(⍴s)⍴⊂'....' create an implicit loop for each character

s←(n←⌽~s=↑l)\s~↑l⋄((~n)/s)←↑l do the relection for first character in l

l←1↓l drop the first character in l

s display the result

⋄ statement separator
```